# How to discern, which machine dumped a process core?

Tags: linux, dump

We have an NFS-share, where processes running on multiple machines occasionally dump cores.

Is there a way to discern -- by looking inside a core-file itself -- which machine dumped it?

Ok, found this [already answered on the "Unix" site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102608/)...

Comment: I do not know if the core file content has the information but otherwise you can request the kernel to choose filenames you like for core files, and hence include some machine identifier of your liking. Of course you need to redo that at each reboot. See http://sinz.org/Michael.Sinz/Linux/core.html and http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/coredump.htm for examples.

Comment: My question is about _existing_ core-dumps. And about figuring out the hostname from the _contents_ of the dump, not from its _name_. But thank you all the same.

Comment: I understood your question, this is why I put a comment not an answer giving you an idea (sorry if you had that already) for future core files. I understand your problem with current core files that are like they are and that you need to inspect their content. I have no idea for now on this specific case but I am searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack suggested in [the earlier discussion of the same problem](//unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102608/) proved useful:

```
% strings core.* | fgrep HOSTNAME=
HOSTNAME=r0125yp30
HOSTNAME=r0125yp10
...
```